# Ask QB to make a check, get check info back later

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I am a python developer, not a QB user, so please forgive me for using poor terminology.

We have an internal web application that is used by finance staff to identify small sets of payment requests for a particular payee.  They then use QB to generate a check to pay that payee.  Then they manually enter the check number and date back into the web app.  I am modifying the web application so that the finance staff can use the app to bundle the payment requests together and - I hope - send a request to QB for the checks, one per payee.  The data to send would be the payee information, the check amount, and whatever else is required.  The data to get back from QB (later) would be the check number and check date and some identifier that I can use to match it up with the requests sent earlier.

What is the best way to implement this communication with QB?

Comment: Update:  Now that we have implemented a solution using iif file for the export from our app and the import of transaction data (one file for requesting checks, another later for creating an invoice), we learn that only QB administrators can import iif files.  Further, the finance department asks why we cannot just use Transaction Pro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use python3, to construct qbXML queries, and Elementree to parse the responses.
I use a non-Windows machine for developement, too. I found that I really needed QB and Python together in a Windows VM to make progress. Both QB and COM require it.

Here are a couple snippets in Python 3.1 to show how I do it:

First, use COM to connect to QuickBooks and disconnect from QuickBooks.

```
import win32com.client

def start(external_application_name):
    """Connect a QuickBooks instance using COM. Start QB if needed"""

    SessionManager = win32com.client.Dispatch("QBXMLRP2.RequestProcessor")
    # Example only - insecure!
    SessionManager.OpenConnection('', external_application_name)
    return SessionManager

def stop(SessionManager):
    """Disconnect from the existing Quickbooks instance."""
    SessionManager.CloseConnection()
    return
```

Next, I use python to do the logic, construct the qbXML queries, and parse the responses into an ElementTree.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

def xml_query(QB_SessionManager, company_file_path, qbXML_query_string):
    """
    Do a QuickBooks QBXML query.
    The query must be valid - this function doesn't do error checking.
    Return an ElementTree of the XML response.
    """
    ticket = QB_SessionManager.BeginSession(company_file_path, 0)
    response_string = QB_SessionManager.ProcessRequest(ticket, qbXML_query_string)
    #print(response_string)   # Debug tool
    SessionManager.EndSession(ticket)
    QBXML = etree.fromstring(response_string)
    response_tree = QBXML.find('QBXMLMsgsRs')
    #etree.dump(QBXML)        # Debug tool
    return response_tree
```

The actual qbXML query string and response string for a check query are on the qbXML reference at https://member.developer.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html
There, you will see that you can download the check data filtered by payee, date range, check number range, etc.

You can chain multiple XML queries or transactions into a single large XML file. Assign each a unique request number (Example: `<CustomerQueryRq requestID="1">` ), so you can locate the proper response.

Use the `<IncludeRetElement>` tag to limit the reply size, and speed the search tremendously.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, much appreciated.  I went on vacation the day before and just got back.  I handed this off to a co-worker and he is the one who noticed your reply while I was out and he is recommending we do something similar.  Thanks!

Comment: I had done complete solution for qb syncronziation, but main issues with multi-threading it does not work.... biggest issue with qb. I manage single thread, but even with single thread only ticket use only and only one time.

Answer (score 1):

As your app is not a SaaS app, so you can use qbsdk for this use case.
sdk download link - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits

IIF files are no longer supported. IIF files can be imported directly into QB, but it would bypass all the business logic.

Comment: @ManusMukherjee, thanks for your reply!  Actually it is a SaaS app, but to avoid communicating through firewalls I think the right thing to do is have my app hand data off to a client side helper app for the single narrow use case of requesting checks from QB inside our firewall.  Based on your answer, I'm now investigating using:

- QuickBooks SDK 12.0
- QBXML Request Processor API
- QuickBooks Web Connector
- Quickbooks Enterprise Solutions: Professional Services 12.0 Release (which finance is using) 

My next hurdle is that I develop on a mac, the QBSDK is obviously only for windows.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately the QuickBooks REST API is not supported for Mac versions of QuickBooks yet only for the Windows Versions as well.

Comment: @JarredKeneally - thanks.  Our finance department runs QB on windows, definitely.  I do my development on a mac, but we have windows boxes we can use for testing or this kind of special case development.